# Automatic Discount for a Certain Member Type

Tags: wordpress, cividiscount, discounts

We have set up various membership types. One of them we want to give a 6 month trial and they renew and pay. We tried to achieve this through CiviDiscount. We set the membership with a value (say USD100) then we give 'Discount for Membership' through CiviDiscount for that membership type. This did not work.

We did see this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17388 and some other related posts. However we are already running the latest versions so still perplexed as to what we are doing wrong.
Here are the Screen Shots:
[image: These are the Membership Types, the one in question is Dealer Silver]
[image: For Dealer Silver We have set a discount of 100%]

These are the Membership Types, the one in question is Dealer Silver.
For 'Dealer - Silver' We have set a discount of 100%.
However when we go and try to register as a member the discount is not getting applied.

CMS : WordPress 4.9.4

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of your settings so that we can see? It's possible that you missed a setting and that is keeping it from working.

Comment: Can you clarify - is the discount not working when the code is entered and the correct membership type is in the "cart"?